# Detecting packet sniffer

Tags: c#, detect, packet, sniffer

I'm writing an network related application and I want to protect it from reverse engineering by shutting it down, if packet sniffer is detected. How can I detect if packet sniffer is running? I could check the running apps and check their names against pre-defined strings (wireshark, httpanalyzer, etc..), but that doesn't seem to be the best way to do it. Is there a way to determinate if application is sniffing packets? Thanks

Comment: Even if you used c++ you can sniff out the packets and reverse engineer the protocol.

Comment: What if network packets are sniffed directly on network devices?

Comment: There is simple no way around it just do it was complicate as possible for some one to reverse such as using encryption for sending receiving packets, timestamps and all sort of things... other then that anyone whiling to and with time will simple reverse it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There is fundamentally no way to do this in general. Most networks in use today are *intended* to send the packets across the network in a manner that permits (or even *requires*) all devices on the cable to see the packets.

You have to get over the concept that your work is so valuable that you need to protect it in this way (or by using copy protection, obfuscation, etc). Protect your application by producing a great application that everyone will want to actually **pay for**.

Answer (score 3):

You know you can run the sniffer on the router using openwrt and there is no way you could detect that.Just encrypt the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't care if they're sniffed directly on network devices. My goal is like Prix sad make it as hard as possible. The problem is that the app is fetching some data from other websites and I don't want people to see what requests am I making, so if they want to fetch the same info, they would have to figure the request header themselves. So there is no way to detect if app is sniffing?

Comment: for that you would need HTTPS which would not show them to where you are doing requests, at least with a simple wire shark sniffing from a HTTPS request i have not seen any URLs.